# MySql: How can I get the latest record for each group by using two datetime fields?

Tags: mysql

I have an `order` table. I want to get the latest record `group by order_placed_at, created_at` for each `user_id`. 
The first two records have the same `order_placed_at` but the first record is the latest `created_at` so I would return record 54447 for user 77.

For user 78 the 4th and 5th records have the same `order_placed_at` but the 4th record has a higher `created_at`. 
What query will return my desired results? I've been trying different queries but getting nowhere.

```
+-------+---------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| id    | user_id | amount    | order_placed_at            | created_at                 |
+-------+---------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 54447 |      77 | 488897.20 | 2020-09-10 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:27.031544 |
| 54441 |      77 | 488983.00 | 2020-09-10 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:26.635398 |
| 53783 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-10 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53784 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-09 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53785 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-09 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:10.816455 |
| 53786 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-08 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53787 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-08 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:20:10.816455 |
| 53788 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-07 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53789 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-07 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:19:10.816455 |
| 53790 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-06 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53791 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-06 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:19:10.816455 |
| 53792 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-06 19:19:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:19:10.816455 |
| 54493 |      78 | 489292.05 | 2020-09-10 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:24.673776 |
| 54494 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-10 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:24.176158 |
| 54495 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-09 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:52:24.176158 |
| 54496 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-09 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:42:20.176158 |
| 54497 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-08 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:24.176158 |
| 54498 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-08 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:20.176158 |
| 54499 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-07 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 05:22:24.176158 |
| 54500 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-07 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:20.176158 |
+-------+---------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Results:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| id    | user_id | amount    | order_placed_at            | created_at                 |
+-------+---------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 54447 |      77 | 488897.20 | 2020-09-10 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:27.031544 |
| 53784 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-09 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53786 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-08 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53788 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-07 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 53790 |      77 | 500728.50 | 2020-09-06 19:20:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:21:18.816455 |
| 54493 |      78 | 489292.05 | 2020-09-10 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:24.673776 |
| 54495 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-09 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:42:20.176158 |
| 54497 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-08 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 04:22:24.176158 |
| 54499 |      78 | 489300.87 | 2020-09-07 19:50:00.000000 | 2020-09-11 05:22:24.176158 |
+-------+---------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

**EDIT**:
**user 77 has records for days 9/6, 9/7, 9/8, 9/9 and 9/10 so i would want the latest record for each day `group by order_placed_at,created_at`
user 78 has records for days 9/7, 9/8, 9/9 and 9/10 so I would want the latest records for each of those days.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS 
( SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_placed_at DESC, created_at DESC) rn
         FROM sourcetable 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

> I updated my question. – MalcolmInTheCenter

```
WITH cte AS 
( SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, DATE(order_placed_at) ORDER BY order_placed_at DESC, created_at DESC) rn
         FROM test 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY user_id, order_placed_at DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa061808050179d350647d4d4b69d523)

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter *last record for each user_id for each day.* Alter `PARTITION BY` expression in window definition and add partitioning level by `DATE(datetime_column)`.

Comment: Sorry I've never used `PARTITION BY` not sure what you mean. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter `... (PARTITION BY user_id, DATE(datetime_column) ORDER BY ...`.  *I've never used PARTITION BY* - Read and study - it is important and useful thing.

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter *that returns one day per user* ??? you must get one row per (user and day). Do you need in something else? if so explain in details - I cannot understand your task correctly. Or maybe create another question - with another sample source data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (t.user_id) t.*
from your_table t
order by t.user_id, t.created_at desc, t.order_placed_at desc
```

I hope this answer can solved your problem.

Comment: I'm getting an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on (t.user_id) t.*.' at line 1

Comment: MySQL does not support DISTINCT ON.